# Rails - Rspec 3 controller action with format.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I'm having a bit of trouble writing rspec tests for controller actions that only respond to js.

Example Controller action:

```
def create
 @user = user.new(user_params)

 respond_to do |format|
   if user.save
     format.js
   end
 end
end
```

Here's some rspec I would write if the controller action responded to html:

```
context 'with valid attributes' do
  it 'creates a new user' do
    expect {
      post :create, user: build(:user)
    }.to change(User,:count).by(1)
  end
```

I am trying to figure out how to write a similar test but make it work with the format js.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this `xhr :post, :create, user: build(:user)`

Comment: Newer way is `post :create, xhr: true, ...`